# How to create a documentation module in OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

I need a documentation module in my OpenXava application. Basically it's to allow the user consult the manual in case of doubt.

I think in HTML format.

I saw in the OpenXava documentation the possibility of creating a documentation module:
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/application_en.html#Application-Documentation%20module

But it only works with Liferay or WebSphere Portal.

Is there a way to do it wihout Liferay or WebSphere Portal?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the documentation modules are only available within a portal, however the help system works without portal and I think it's just what you're looking for. It can be activated configuring some properties in xava.properties.

Note the Help part in the following doc:

https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/customizing_en.html#Customizing-Xava%20Properties%20Settings

Something like this in xava.properties could work for you:

```
helpAvailable=true
helpPrefix=help/
```

If the help is a folder called 'help' inside your application.

Also you can put the help in another server:

```
helpPrefix=https://www.example.com/help
```

If it ends with underscore it can have multilanguage support, thus:

```
helpPrefix=https://www.example.com/myapplication/help_
```

Where it looks for help_en.html, help_es.html or help_fr.html, depending on the browser language.